# Hibernate HSQLDB - DuplicateMappingException

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I'm writing simple "todo" application in Spring Boot.
I'm using HSQLDB in my development environment.

I've got two tables "Project" and "Task". 
Task table has one to many reference to project's table because I want to list all tasks in projects.

When I try to run my app I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1170) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1159) [spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at pl.mattscode.taskman.TaskmanApplication.main(TaskmanApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Same physical table name [project] references several logical table names: [project], [Project]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addTableBinding(Configuration.java:3172) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.buildAndFillTable(TableBinder.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.buildAndFillTable(TableBinder.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindTable(EntityBinder.java:594) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:677) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

This is my hibernate entities classes:

**Project**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "project_id")
  private Long projectId;

  @Column
  private String name;

  public Long getId() {
      return projectId;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
     this.projectId = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**Task**

```
 @Entity
  public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private List<Project> projectId;

    public List<Project> getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(List<Project> projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And this is the way how I query the database.

**ProjectRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
    @Query("select t.name from Task t inner join Project p on t.id = p.id")
    List<Task> getProjectsWithTasks();
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

**EDIT:** 
I added `@Table(name="project")`, change `@JoinTable` to `@JoinColumn` and I have another error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pl.mattscode.taskman.task.repository.entity.Task.projectId references an unknown entity: java.util.List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `@ManytoOne` then the field type should not be a list, if you want a collection of Projects then it should be `@OneToMany` annotation

I have modified the files if you would like to try them.

```
@Entity
public class Project
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private Long projectId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private List<Task> task;

    public List<Task> getTask()
    {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(final List<Task> task)
    {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.projectId = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
@Entity
public class Task
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: I changed to @OneToMany and it's still the same (org.hibernate.AnnotationException:)

Comment: I have edited my response with those two entities, please check if they solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Could explain that why I made mistake?

Comment: Your requirement was to add multiple tasks to your project, so it has to be OnetoMany on Project with a list of tasks. Also you do not need Table annotation when your Entity name is same as table name.

Answer (score 0):

@JoinTable is trying to create another table entry with same name Project. In  your Task Entity replace:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="project",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"))
```

to

```
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
```

Comment: Is it still DuplicateMappingException? or some other eror?

Comment: It's another org.hibernate.AnnotationException. I pasted it at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I had two entity classes referring to same table. I was using only one file . It did not had any issue with mysql db but for oracle after googling and stuff i solved the issue by deleting that other entity class .
So keep only one entity class per table dnt keep two not even for some other reason.